# Is it possible to have dynamic batchsize in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

Keras codes I have looked or wrote have fixed batchsize during training (i.e. 32, 64, 128 ...). I am wondering if it is possible to have dynamic batchsize. (For example, 104 in the first iteration, 82 in the next iteration, 95 in next, and so on.)

I am currently using tensorflow backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible if you train on a loop vs training with fit. an example

```
from random import shuffle    

dataSlices = [(0,104),(104,186),(186,218)]

for epochs in range(0,10):
    shuffle(dataSlices)
    for i in dataSlices:
        x,y = X[i[0]:i[1],:],Y[i[0]:i[1],:]
        model.fit(x,y,epochs=1,batchsize=x.shape[0])
        #OR as suggest by Daniel Moller
        #model.train_on_batch(x,y)
```

This would assume your data is 2d numpy arrays. This idea can be further expanded to use a `fit_generator()` inplace of the for loop if you so choose (see [docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/)).

Comment: You can probably use `train_on_batch` for that instead of `fit`. (This may eliminate some overhead).

Comment: Thanks, djk47463 and Daniel Möller! It helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `None` to set any batch size. In particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240348/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-none-in-model-summary-of-keras) explains it.