# I was reading a book on Deep learning and I am not able to understand this part about Conv2D

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

```
Layer (type) Output Shape Param #
================================================================
conv2d_4 (Conv2D) (None, 26, 26, 32) 320
________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D) (None, 24, 24, 64) 18496
________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D) (None, 22, 22, 64) 36928
================================================================
Total params: 55,744
Trainable params: 55,744
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The author says:

> The 3 × 3 windows
> in the third layer will only contain information coming from 7 × 7 windows in
> the initial input. The high-level patterns learned by the convnet will still be very
> small with regard to the initial input, which may not be enough to learn to classify digits (try recognizing a digit by only looking at it through windows that are
> 7 × 7 pixels!). We need the features from the last convolution layer to contain
> information about the totality of the input.

Now where did this 7x7 window come from?Isnt the window in first layer also 3X3 ? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider this example:

```
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',input_shape=(28,28,3)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(20, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(10, (3, 3), activation='relu')])
```

Here is the output of the model.summary():

```
        Model: "sequential_1"
        _________________________________________________________________
        Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
        =================================================================
        conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 26, 26, 32)        896       
                                                                        
        conv2d_4 (Conv2D)           (None, 24, 24, 20)        5780      
                                                                        
        conv2d_5 (Conv2D)           (None, 22, 22, 10)        1810      
                                                                        
        =================================================================
        Total params: 8,486
        Trainable params: 8,486
        Non-trainable params: 0
        _________________________________________________________________
```

To calculate the output shape you could use this formula:

```
O = (W - K + 2P)/S + 1
```

where O is the output height/width, W is the input height/width, K is the filter size, P is the padding and S is the stride size.

To calculate the Parameter Number for conv_layer you could use this formula:

`param_number_for_conv_layer = output_channel_number * (input_channel_number * kernel_height * kernel_width + 1)`

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240348/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-none-in-model-summary-of-keras) for 'None' in the output shape